# What are best/easiest Apache server/folder settings for allowing a python script to create a file?

Tags: php, python, linux, apache

I have a simple Python script in folder "fold" that is launched from a PHP file. It creates a file on the same directory then exits back to PHP.

```
f = open("t.txt","w")
f.write("test")
f.close()
```

You can call it from PHP with:

```
$proc=proc_open("fold/simple.py",array(0=>array('pipe','r'),1=>array('pipe','w'),2=>array('pipe','w')),$pipes);
```

or

```
execute("python fold/simple.py");
```

etc..

The settings that seemed logical to me were:

- I added the apache group among the owners of the folder and the python file.
- I allowed write for the group over that folder.
- I set the python file to executable for all.

This seems normal right? However, the error reported from PHP is that there are no write rights. I also tested the user from PHP with:

```
echo 'current user :'.exec('whoami');
```

and it is "apache", and it obviously belongs to the homonym group.

So, where do I go wrong, and what settings satisfy the balance between being the best and the most simple? Thanks!

Comment: Well the obvious answer is to just `chmod 777` the directory in question - but I take it there is some reason you don't want to do this? Also, what is the code that generates the `no write rights` error? What (and where) are you checking to come to this conclusion, exactly?

Comment: Of course chmod 777 is the simplest solution yet the worst possible out of security concerns. To get the error I piped the standard error stream to php, the exact text of it I cant recall but it was the usual python error when the writing rights are disabled over a folder.

Comment: I am actually surprised not to find a good recipe for this on the Internet, I expected all python web development tutorials to start with this!

Comment: While I can't even begin to argue with your security best-practice approach, I would question how necessary it is here. In a web server environment, it can (generally) be assumed that the only thing that is likely to make undesired changes to a folder is a web-based app, and if you are giving `apache` full control over the folder, *all* web apps on the server that run under that user will be able to change it anyway. Having said that, I agree it is very much desirable to find a solution that doesn't involve `chmod 777`.

Comment: Suggest you check the CWD from within the PHP/python apps and/or remove relative paths from both apps (temporarily - just to make sure everything is singing from the same hymn sheet)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting my solution is the best plus it is not even working (and I don't know why). I used chmod777 for development but now we must deploy.

Comment: Can you `chown apache` the directory? That way, you can `chmod 700` it if you want - it should still allow you to do what you need, and remove the possibility of other users making undesired changes...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4551/discussion-between-grokkaine-and-daverandom)

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, I suggest you create a directory which is only for creating files by your program, maybe files or something, and set the permission to 777(chmod -R 777 files), and other directory should be 755, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

As said by everybody, in general it's not good to set a directory with 777 rights! It is not necessary if you understand where your script is working!

But, to answer your question, the solution should be changing the rights to apache:apache to the folder where you want to write and, more than this, don't rely on relative paths for the files that you want to run/read/write, but specify always an absolute path: in python you can do this prepending the filename you want to write with something like...

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath
basedir = dirname(abspath(__file__)) + '/'
```